# Failed to export Java class to JavaScript via JsInterop in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I'm following the GWT documentation [Coding Basics - JavaScript: JsInterop](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html) to export a Java class to JavaScript via annotation `@JsMethod`. However, the Java class is not transpiled into JavaScript.

Here's my Java class:

```
package io.mincongh.client;

import jsinterop.annotations.JsMethod;

public class ExportedMethods {

  @JsMethod
  public static String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Hello, " + name;
  }
}
```

And my project is built in Maven, via GWT Maven plugin 2.8.2:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>test</goal>
        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <runTarget>StockMarket.html</runTarget>
    <modules>
      <module>io.mincongh.StockMarket</module>
    </modules>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I call the exported method in my browser's console. Then the method is not defined:

> ```
> io.mincongh.client.ExportedMethods.sayHello('world');
> ```
>
> VM59:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
>      at :1:1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specification [JsInterop v1.0:
Nextgen GWT/JavaScript Interoperability](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit#), paragraph *@JsType*:

> Note that exporting of Java Objects to JavaScript to be accessed by their namespace (e.g. this sample) requires `--generateJsInteropExports` flag.

So you need to specify this flag in the Maven GWT plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  ...
  <configuration>
    <generateJsInteropExports>true</generateJsInteropExports>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```